# Pass variable from route to blade view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have app in Laravel and Vue.js. In navbar.blade.php I did something like this:

```
<p>{!! $test !!}</p>
```

Now I want to change that variable to text using only routing. Can I do it? How?

If not, how I can keep that variable but change it in vue.js?

Comment: Put your js code as well

Comment: you can take variable in route parameter And pass it to view through controller

Comment: @MeeraTank not all my viewss are using controller

Comment: If you are calling view from route function it will also work  same

Comment: @MeeraTank Can you explain me this?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try like

```
Route::get('path/{test}', function ($test) {
    return view('viewblade', ['test' => $test]);
});
```

Hope these will Help.

Comment: Tried like this:
        Route::get('/page', [
            'uses' => 'Controller@index',
            'test' => $test,
        ]);
and i grt undefined variable test in this code

Comment: That's not what I want.
I have navbar and I include it in my components. Now I want to have different text on all pages.

Comment: @RowinskiBartosz you can pass variable in redirection check : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions it's not like you had mentioned

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment,

> I have navbar and I include it in my components. Now I want to have different text on all pages.

I think you can make use of Blade `yield`. I'm assuming you are using Blade `extends`

Change your `<p>` tag in your nav `components` from

```
<p>{!! $test !!}</p>
```

To

```
<p>@yield('testValue')</p>
```

and in every page, add this after `@extends(....)`

```
@section('testValue', 'MyValueSpecificToThisPage')
```

Hope it's helpful.